# Calculating the spectrogram of the center of pressure time series in human standing balance

Tags: spectrogram, time-frequency

I have some biomechanical data of a few subjects standing on a force plate. The center of pressure along the x and y axes was measured. The total time of measurement was 30s and the sampling frequency was 100Hz.

I want to observe if there is any reduction of the density P(t,ω) in higher frequencies as time passes.

I see that there are many time-frequency analysis methods and I was wondering which would be the best method to answer my question.

I have also another question. I inserted one signal after detrending the mean in the signal analyzer app in MATLAB but I am using it for the first time and it is like a black box for me. Which method does it use? Is it even suitable for my purpose?

Comment: By *"...reduction of density [...] in higher frequencies..."*, you mean a reduction of high frequency content in the signal?

Comment: @A_A yes exactly that